# Linearlayout with rounded corners and image resource background?

Tags: android

Is such a thing possible?

I am trying:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/smoke_bg" />
</item>

<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And setting that as my linearlayouts background but it is still not working. I just get a rectangle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318454/android-layout-background-xml-texture/21326664#21326664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="72dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_image" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_image"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="70dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:paddingBottom="2sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2sp"
                android:paddingRight="2sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Title Of Song -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- Artist Name -->

        <cTextView
            android:id="@+id/producid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="12dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoriid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Border.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#979797" />

    <padding
        android:left="1sp"
        android:right="1sp"
        android:top="1sp" />

    <corners android:radius="1dip" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="0dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <solid android:color="#fbc9c3"  />

    <corners android:radius="14dp" />

</shape>
```

Change the following to increase/decrease corner:

```
<corners android:radius="14dp" />
```

Comment: This does not help me, as I need an image as the background, not a solid colour.